# How to split the value uploaded in Access table?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have uploaded a spreadsheet in the access and want to remove the part of value after the underscore.

like: Value in Table : FDS-11-1042_TripReport

I want to run a query that give me FDS-11-1042 and remove the part after the underscore.

i want to use function in Query design view.

[image: database image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access?

Comment: There is no Split_Part function in Access-2010

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, you can use `left()` and `instr()`:

```
 left(col, instr(col, "_") - 1)
```

If the underscore is optional:

```
 left(col, instr(col & "_", "_") - 1)
```

Comment: This formula will 1) store the underscore if it is present 2) give empty string if underscore is not present.

Comment: thank you its working but still underscore is present. To run query on PE-680_TripReport , it gives result : PE-680_. but I need only PE-680 Only. how to do it?

Comment: @MUHAMMADISHTIAQKHAN . . . I already updated the answer to subtract 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name, 
       IIf(InStr(column_name,"_"),
           Left(column_name,InStr(column_name,"_")-1),
           column_name) AS Expression1
FROM table_name;
```